# How to filter array values from another arrays values and return new array?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, filter, array-filter

I have two arrays: `$all_languages` and `$taken_languages`. One contains all languages (like 200 or something), but second - languages that have been chosen before (from 0 to 200).

I need to remove all languages that have been taken (`$taken_languages`) from `$all_languages` and return new array - `$available_languages`.

My solution was two loops, but, first, it doesn't work as expected, second - it's 'not cool' and I believe that there are better solutions! Can you point me to the correct path?

This is what I have done before, but, as I said, it doesn't work as expected...

```
if (!empty($taken_languages)) {

    foreach ($all_languages as $language) {

        foreach ($taken_languages as $taken_language) {

            if ($taken_language != $language) {

                $available_languages[] = $language;

                break;

            }

        }

    }

} else {

    $available_languages = $all_languages;

}
```

Thanks in advice!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

PHP has a built in function for this (and just about everything else :P)

```
$available_languages = array_diff($all_languages, $taken_languages);
```

[PHP Manual (array_diff)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)

Answer (score 3):

The `array_diff` function will work for you.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php