# php and deleteing variable on from 2 array

Tags: php, arrays

```
Array1
(
    [0] => 14
    [1] => 9
    [2] => 10
    [3] => 11
)


Array2
(
    [0] => 8
    [1] => 9
    [2] => 10
    [3] => 11
    [4] => 12
    [5] => 13
    [6] => 14
    [7] => 15
    [8] => 16
    [9] => 17
    [10] => 18
    [11] => 19
    [12] => 20
    [13] => 21
    [14] => 22
    [15] => 23
    [16] => 24
```

some function to delete the array1 values on array 2 and create a array3 whit the results ?

thanks !

Comment: You could use array_merge and array_unique.

Comment: function array_remove_by_value($arr, $value)
{ return array_values(array_diff($arr, array($value)));}
foreach($ares as $keys => $values)
{$arr = array_remove_by_value($arr, $values);}

Comment: i know this is not a service but im do this but android studio send me a error sow i want to know some other ways

Comment: Android Studio you said? Is this in PHP, or Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array_diff function is what you're looking for. Credit to Paulpro for the source of where I found this function: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7241152/4912760.
Code example for your case:

```
$array3 = array_diff($array2, $array1);
```

Comment: thanks bro you save mi day 6 hours try do this , really thanks

Comment: @chris85 From http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php: array array_diff ( array $array1 , array $array2 [, array $... ] )     Compares array1 against one or more other arrays and returns the values in array1 that are not present in any of the other arrays.